# Export Craft Data

Tags: plugins, localization

I need to export all content from a Website to be translated by a translation company.

Is there some sort of content export plugin who exports the content into a readable form?

The other option is to give the translators access to the control panel. But I'm a bit hesitant about this. Translators shouldn't fight with matrix fields and such, I guess.

Comment: How are they going to supply the translation back to you without access to the CP? You could export through regular templates. that outputs the data in a readable form (with simple design) - but you still need to think about input.

Comment: I thought somebody with cp experience would re-enter the whole data. Because the sites relies heavily on content elements, the translators would have to build quite a big amount of page layouts which I think is not in their competence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to handle this is by using the **[Export](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/export)** and **[Import](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import)** tools by Bob Olde Hampsink. This will allow you to output the data to a CSV file, which you can hand off to the translator. Be wary though, if you have any complex fields (like custom field types), they may or may not export/import easily.

I would also strongly consider giving your translator temporary access to the CP. You could give them a temporary account with limited access, and point them straight to the pages which need translating. While your concerns over things like Matrix fields are valid, I'm not sure they outweigh the extra overhead of the exporting/importing process.

When used with Live Preview, giving access to the control panel also lets your translators see the strings they are translating used in the context of the site itself, which is useful when there might be multiple translations for a string.

Comment: The *Import* and *Export* plugins **do not support matrix fields** (or fields for other plugins like *Neo*). So they're quite limited currently.

Comment: Export plugin is deprecated? Any alternatives to export data ? I have a Craft3 website and I need to export categories

Comment: @SimonFranzen If you have a new question (ie: "Are there any alternatives to the deprecated Export plugin?"), I'd recommend you [ask it as a new question...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: dear @LindseyD, I created a new question: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26017/are-there-any-alternatives-to-the-deprecated-export-plugin  Do you want to join me promoting it ?