# Are there any alternatives to the deprecated Export plugin?

Tags: plugins, craft3, json, csv, export

This thread [Export Craft Data](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11366/export-craft-data/11375?noredirect=1#comment34104_11375) leads me to add a new question.

**What is a good Craft 3 export plugin?**

I know several for imports, for example the FeedMe plugin is doing a great job, but nothing to export data.

What I need:

- Export buttons for all views in CP. (Columns can be defined)
- related entries/categories can be included in the export
- in an extra view you can prepare templates of exports (like in the Wordpress plugin WPAllExport)
- It should also be possible to define a path where it exports the data on a regular basis

(And I think you can imagine much more benefits...)

And NO, the ElementAPI Plugin does not fit my needs. It has to be Client-Usable.

We created a lot of web applications where we always implement some kind of export. If there is nothing out there I am really thinking of creating a plugin. Is there anyone else out there willing to support an ideal **Export Plugin** (and is also willing to pay for a Pro Version )

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to export to a CSV, I'd recommend trying the Sprout Reports plugin...

> https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/reports